# BOSH implementation on ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I tried to start BOSH on ejabberd. My ejabberd.cfg snippet is below:

```
   {5280, ejabberd_http, [
                     {request_handlers, [
            {["xmpp-httpbind"], mod_http_bind}
         ]},
         captcha,
         http_bind, 
         http_poll, 
         web_admin
            ]}

http://localhost:5280/http-bind fails to open any page.
```

And my client getting this response from server

Sent XML:

```
<iq to='localhost' id='uid:50502b03:00004823' type='get' x
mlns='jabber:client'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:auth'><username>anurag</username></
query></iq>
```

Received XML:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='localhost' id='uid:505
029df:00004823' type='error'><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailabl
e xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>


Sent XML: </stream:stream>
auth failed. reason: 0
ce: 18
```

I am using gloox library to create a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add {mod_http_bind, []} to your modules section?

Comment: Yes I added this module. My mistake was using localhost as hostname. After correcting hostname it start working. Thanks @Ed209.